# Objects in HTML5 Canvas leave trail during animation

Tags: javascript, html, animation, html5-canvas

I am trying to animate the html5 canvas, and I have created objects for each of my elements in it. First of all, I call the objects on a separate javascript file, draw the images, and run a gameLoop which handles their movement/the animation, like so:

```
//Draws a canvas on the screen
spiel.drawCanvas(800,600, "#FFF000");

//Creates a new Rectangle object, then calls the draw function inside it
var rect1 = new spiel.Rectangle(10,10, 100,100, "#FF00FF");
rect1.draw();

//Creates a new circle object, then calls the draw function inside it
var circ1 = new spiel.Circle(300, 300, 30, "#00FF00");
circ1.draw();

//Calls the gameLoop function, which executes a requestAnimationFrame, and then executes what is inside the function argument every frame
spiel.gameLoop(function(){
//Moves the rectangle object downwards with a velocity of 2 pixels per iteration
rect1.moveDown(2);

//Moves the circle object to the left with a velocity of 1 pixel per iteration
circ1.moveLeft(1);
});
```

These objects/functions are stored inside another javascript file. Here is some of that code:

**The gameLoop**

```
gameLoop : function gameLoop(func){
requestAnimationFrame(function(){gameLoop(func); func();});
},
```

**The Rectangle draw and animate**

```
//Draws a recatngle on the screen
this.draw = function(){
c.fillStyle = this.color;
c.fillRect(this.posX, this.posY, this.width, this.height);
}

//These functions move the created rectangle in a certain direction
this.moveLeft = function moveLeft(velocity){
    this.velocity = velocity;
    c.clearRect(this.posX, this.posY, this.width, this.height);
    this.posX -= this.velocity;
    c.fillStyle = this.color;
    c.fillRect(this.posX, this.posY, this.width, this.height);
}
```

**The Circle Draw and Animate**

```
//Draw the circle on the screen
this.draw = function(){
  c.beginPath();
  c.arc(this.posX, this.posY, this.radius, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
  c.fillStyle = this.color;
  c.fill();
  c.closePath();
}

//These functions move the circlular object on certain directions
this.moveLeft = function moveLeft(velocity){
  this.velocity = velocity;
  c.save();
  c.globalCompositeOperation = 'destination-out';
  c.beginPath();
  c.arc(this.posX, this.posY, this.radius, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
  c.fill();
  c.restore();

  this.posX -= this.velocity;

  c.beginPath();
  c.arc(this.posX, this.posY, this.radius, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
  c.fillStyle = this.color;
  c.fill();
  c.lineWidth = 0;
  c.strokeStyle = this.color;
  c.stroke();
  c.closePath();
}
```

My problem is, when I test this, these objects leave a trail on the canvas, especially the circle. I took a screenshot of the canvas :

[image: Canvas Screenshot]

What is causing this? What can I do to fix it?

Thanks a lot for reading, and thank you in advance for the answer!

**EDIT:** I added `c.translate(1, 1);` upon creating the canvas, and now the trace that the rectangle object leaves does not appear anymore, but the circle trail is still there. From experimenting with different velocities, it appears to me as the trail that the circle leaves could be it's stroke/border. Is it possible that the stroke/border is not being cleared?

Comment: At first glance, it looks like an anti-aliasing problem (that I'm not sure how to fix).

Comment: @byxor I tried disabling anti-aliasing via `c.imageSmoothingEnabled = false;` , but the problem is still apparent. Thank you for the suggestion though!

Comment: Clear the whole canvas, then redraw all object. Colour channels are 8Bit and that means there will always be some error in pixel values.Clearing the whole canvas is the easiest solution and standard practice for 99% of animations.

Comment: @Blindman67 That's insane unless your canvas is _really_ small.

Comment: @destoryer By  "*really* small" do you mean 1920 by 1080? GPU's are tuned to the device and can clear a screen in well under a ms.

Comment: @Blindman67 It's the redrawing that worries me.

Comment: @destoryer Have you tried rendering? I budget 500 (images, or path2D) render calls per frame to cover the average laptop and get 60fps. Or in pixel counts about 25*display res (~50million pixels per frame 1920*1080) And half that for a tablet 12 * display res. These are approximations and will depend on other factors and all code is heavily optimized. If you need more use WebGL and you can crank out 16000 to 32000 translated, rotated,scaled,alpha faded sprites on mid range machines easy,